GoogleDriveAPIを利用した共有ドライブ上のフォルダーの移動が上手くいきません
共有ドライブ上にあるフォルダーの移動(親フォルダーの変更)についてお教え下さい。
JavaからGoogle Drive APIを利用して、Google Drive上の共有ドライブに在るフォルダーを移動(親フォルダーの変更)を行おうとしており、GCPにプロジェクトを作成し試験をしていますが、上手くいきません。
何かヒントや参考資料の紹介でも結構ですので、頂戴できると助かります。
手順は以下です。
1.リフレッシュトークンを取得。
GCPにプロジェクトを作成を作成し、リフレッシュトークン等を取得します。
この時に利用したユーザIDは開発者のIDです。
開発者のIDで目的の共有ドライブ上のフォルダーを手動で(ブラウザーで)移動
する事は可能です。
Javaプログラムの中で、以下の順序で処理をしています。
2.取得したリフレッシュトークンとGoogle Drive APIを利用してアクセストークンを取得。
3.移動対象のフォルダーID、 移動前の親フォルダーID、 移動後の親フォルダーID
を利用してフォルダーを移動します。
各フォルダーIDは、ブラウザーのURLの末尾
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/ここの部分 を取得しています。
フォルダーの構成は以下のイメージです。
変更前
共有ドライブ -+--  移動前の親フォルダー  ---  移動フォルダー
　　　　　　　+--  移動後の親フォルダー

となっており、以下となる事を期待していますが、移動しません。
変更後
共有ドライブ -+--  移動前の親フォルダー
　　　　　　　+--  移動後の親フォルダー  ---  移動フォルダー

対象のフォルダー「移動フォルダー」を「移動前の親フォルダー」から「移動後の親フォルダー」へ移動(親フォルダーの変更)させたく思います。
結果はリターンコードは200(正常)を返していますが、GoogleDrive上のフォルダーは元のままで移動されていません。なお、手動で移動を実施すると移動します。
以下にソースを添付します。
    /**
     * 親フォルダーを変更する
     * targetFolderID: 変更対象のフォルダーID
     * oldParentID: 変更前の親のフォルダーID
     * newParentID: 変更後の親のフォルダーID
     *    HTTP リクエスト
     *      PATH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/targetFolderID
     */
    private  File  changeFolderPatrnt( String targetFolderId, String oldParentId, String newParentId ){

        System.out.println( "" );
        System.out.println( "親フォルダーを変更する" );
        
        String    endPoint2;        
        
        endPoint2    =    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
        endPoint2    =    endPoint2 +  "/"  +  String.format( "%s", targetFolderId );
        endPoint2    =    endPoint2 +  "?supportsAllDrives=true";
        System.out.println( "endPoint2=" + endPoint2 );
        
        //変更前の親フォルダーID
        List<String>tempOldParentId;
        tempOldParentId    =    new ArrayList<String>();
        tempOldParentId.add(oldParentId);
        
        //変更前の後フォルダーID
        List<String>tempNewParentId;
        tempNewParentId    =    new ArrayList<String>();
        tempNewParentId.add(newParentId);
        
        //ＰＡＴＣＨデータの生成
        HttpResponse<String>        response        =    null;
        String                      responseBody    =    "";
        
        Map<String, Object> postParmMap = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println( "postParmJMap=" + postParmMap );

        //PATCH送信
        try {
        
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build();

            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create( endPoint2 ))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken )
                .header("fields", "id,name,parents" )                                   //取得するフィールド
                .header("removeParents", String.join( ",", tempOldParentId ))           //変更前の親フォルダーID
                .header("addParents", String.join( ",", tempNewParentId ))              //変更後の親フォルダーID
                .method("PATCH", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(new Gson().toJson(postParmMap)))
                .build();
               System.out.println( "request=" + request );
               System.out.println( "request.headers=" + request.headers() );
               response         =    httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
               responseBody    =    response.body();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("エラー\n"+e.getMessage());
                System.exit(40);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("エラー\n"+e.getMessage());
                System.exit(30);
        }
        int        statusCode        =    response.statusCode();
        
        System.out.println( "statusCode=" + statusCode );
        System.out.println( "response=" + response );
        System.out.println( "responseBody=" + responseBody );
        
        //レスポンスが正常なら
        if ( statusCode == 200) {
            File    targetFolder    =    gson.fromJson(responseBody, File.class);
            System.out.println( "親フォルダー変更成功" );
            System.out.println( "Id=" + targetFolder.id );
            System.out.println( "Name=" + targetFolder.name );
            System.out.println( "Parents=" + targetFolder.parents );
            
            return        targetFolder;
            
        }  else  {
            System.out.println( "親フォルダー変更失敗" );
            return        null;
        }
        
    }

共有ドライブ上に、フォルダを作成する、フォルダーをゴミ箱へ移動する、フォルダーをリネームする、ファイルのアップロード等は成功しておりますが、親ディレクトリーの変更は上手くいきません。
以下に出力したデバック情報を示します。
親フォルダーを変更する
endPoint2=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/移動フォルダーのId?supportsAllDrives=true
postParmJMap={}
request=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/移動フォルダーのId?supportsAllDrives=true PATCH
request.headers=java.net.http.HttpHeaders@12063e1 { {addParents=[移動後の親フォルダー], Authorization=[Bearer アクセストークン], Content-Type=[application/json; charset=UTF-8], fields=[id,name,parents], removeParents=[移動前の親フォルダー]} }
statusCode=200
response=(PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/移動フォルダーのId?supportsAllDrives=true) 200
responseBody={
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "移動フォルダーのId",
  "name": "移動フォルダー",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
  "teamDriveId": "共有ドライブのId",
  "driveId": "共有ドライブのId"
}

親フォルダー変更成功
Id=移動フォルダーのId
Name=移動フォルダー
Parents=null

なお、以下の様に、PATCHの中身としてremoveParents、addParentsを送って
みましたが、反応は同様でした。
        Map<String, Object> postParmMap = new HashMap<>();
        postParmMap.put("kind", "drive#file" );                                    //Kind
        postParmMap.put("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" );        //mimeType
        postParmMap.put("fields","id,name,parents");                               //取得するフィールド
        postParmMap.put("removeParents", String.join( ",", tempOldParentId ) );    //変更前の親フォルダーID
        postParmMap.put("addParents", String.join( ",", tempNewParentId ) );       //変更後の親フォルダーID
         
        .method("PATCH", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(new Gson().toJson(postParmMap)))


自己解決致しました、大変お騒がせ致しました。
以下の様にURLの後ろにパラメータを記述した所、動く様になりました。
endPoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files";
endPoint = endPoint + "/" + String.format( "%s", targetFolderId );
endPoint = endPoint + "?supportsAllDrives=true";
endPoint = endPoint + "&corpora=drive";
endPoint = endPoint + "&driveId=" + DRIVE_ID;
endPoint = endPoint + "&fields=" + fieldsStr2; 
endPoint = endPoint + "&removeParents=" + String.join( ",", tempOldParentId ); 
endPoint = endPoint + "&addParents=" + String.join( ",", tempNewParentId ); 

